# Obter atributo valor de elementos do modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá,

Observando `objeto_receita` obtenho os seguintes dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após receber estes dados, eu atribuo o seu valor aos respectivos campos.

Usando basicamente a função abaixo:

```
function objeto_form() {
    $('#txt-descricao').val(objeto_receita.descricao);
}
```

Quanto a isso, tudo certo, consigo preencher o form normalmente.

Mas ao verificar no html, percebo que o value do elemento, está vazio.

Portanto, como posso obter, o value do elemento?

Sei que desta forma, eu consigo `$('#sel-conta').val();`

Mas porque este elemento está vazio, quando visto no html ?

Usando a função abaixo, me mostra um valor vazio.

```
function(elem){
    var value = elem.value;
    var id    = elem.id;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: como é que você está se certificando que `objeto_receita.descricao` realmente contém algo, e que a função está sendo chamada de fato? E tem certeza de não ter mais de um ID igual na página?

Comment: Se eu olhar no console eu consigo ver, fora isso, o campo descrição está sendo populado.

Comment: E onde é que está verificando o HTML? Tem que lembrar que se houver qualquer mudança de página, o valor não persiste.

Comment: tudo bem, estou ciente, o valor está sendo recuperado e exibido no campo, porem no modal, ao checar o value manualmente, não consigo ver o atributo valor.

Comment: Gostaria de saber como é que o bootstrap modal obtem o seta o valor recuperado, sem preencher o `data-value`.

Comment: Seria legal se tivesse como [edit] e fornecer mais detalhes, só pelo que vc passou fica dificil testarmos, sem um contexto adequado. As possibilidades são muitas, e o que tem na pergunta é muito limitado. Se pudesse reduzir seu código a um [mcve] ajudaria.

Comment: Já tentou selecionar o elemento no inspetor e escrever no console: `$0.value` ?? Talvez você esteja confundindo o conceito de propriedade e de atributos.

Comment: Editei a pergunta e tentei explicar melhor.

Já selecionei o elemento através do element.value e está vazio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atributos e propriedades são coisas separadas, quando você inspeciona o HTML você está vendo os atributos dos elementos, quando você está trabalhando com um `HMLTInputElement` no seu javascript você está vendo suas propriedades.

O navegador vai ler seu HTML, reconhecer seus atributos e montar os objetos com suas propriedades se baseando nestes atributos. Não há necessidade de você espelhar cada mudança nas propriedades em seus atributos relacionados. Basta usar javascript e inspecionar seus valores por console.

Você pode acessar os atributos do HTML através do método [`HTMLElement.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) e as propriedades são acessadas diretamente do objeto javascript. Ex:

```
console.log(element.value)
```

Para exemplificar o conceito, abaixo um exemplo onde é printado o estado inicial, alterada a propriedade e depois alterado o atributo. Você verá que um não reflete no outro.

```js
let input = document.getElementById('teste')

console.log("-- Estado inicial")
console.log("Propriedade:", input.value)
console.log("Atributo:", input.getAttribute('value'))

console.log("-- Alterada a propriedade 'value'")
input.value = "valor da propriedade"
console.log("Propriedade:", input.value)
console.log("Atributo:", input.getAttribute('value'))

console.log("-- Alterado o atributo 'value'")
input.setAttribute('value', 'Novo valor do atributo')
console.log("Propriedade:", input.value)
console.log("Atributo:", input.getAttribute('value'))
```

```html
<input id="teste" value="valor do atributo" />
```

Comment: Certo, compreendi um pouco o que quis dizer.. mas se tratando de um modal dialog, como obter o atributo value, ou inserir este atributo no elemento ? estou questionando porque estou usando um plugin, e o plugin verifica este atributo.

https://github.com/geminilabs/float-labels.js

Comment: Teria que ver na documentação da biblioteca, não seria: `floatlabels.rebuild();`?

Comment: Já tentei, ok. ao menos sua resposta já esclarece sobre o uso das propriedades e atributos. obrigado pela resposta

Answer (score 0):

O `jquery .val('value')` não atualiza o DOM, caso queira realmente atualizar isso use o `jquery .attr`.

Exemplo:

```
$('#txt-descricao').val('novo valor');    
//after jQuery 1.5.2
$('#txt-descricao').attr('value', 'novo valor');
```

Leia esse tópico exatamente sobre essa questão (Em inglês):
https://www.willis-owen.co.uk/jquery-changing-form-values-not-affecting-the-dom/

Espero ter ajudado!